# Get feature importance from trained Vertex AI Tabular regression model using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-automl, google-ai-platform

I am working with models trained using the Tabular automl of Vertex in GCP.
Training and batch predictions work fine. I am truing to use the feature importance in visualizations and trying to get to them from within python.
I can get to the model:

```
client = aiplatform.gapic.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
name = client.model_path(project=project, location='us-central1', model=modelnum)
response = client.get_model(name=name)
```

But I can not figure out how to get the trained model's feature importance's that were generated in the training pipeline. I can see them on the model page but can't access them from python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get details on the "Evaluate" page, you need to use [list_model_evaluations()](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/model_service.html#google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient.list_model_evaluations). This will return `google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.model_service.pagers.ListModelEvaluationsPager` that contains the values you see on "Evaluate" page. Since you mentioned you want to get the feature importance, you need to loop through the said object and get `model_explanation`. See code below:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform

api_endpoint = 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint} # api_endpoint is required for client_options
client_model = aiplatform.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
project_id = 'your-project-id'
location = 'us-central1'
model_id = '9999999999999'

model_name = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
list_eval_request = aiplatform.types.ListModelEvaluationsRequest(parent=model_name)
list_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluations(request=list_eval_request)
for val in list_eval:
    print(val.model_explanation)
```

For the testing, I used Google's sample data (gs://cloud-ml-tables-data/bank-marketing.csv).

**Response from the code:**

```
mean_attributions {
  feature_attributions {
    struct_value {
      fields {
        key: "Age"
        value {
          number_value: 0.027145349596062344
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Balance"
        value {
          number_value: 0.009469658279914696
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Campaign"
        value {
          number_value: 0.009621628534664564
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Contact"
        value {
          number_value: 0.006477007587775141
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Day"
        value {
          number_value: 0.013976069802316006
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Default"
        value {
          number_value: 1.528606850783311e-08
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Duration"
        value {
          number_value: 0.1395725763431482
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Education"
        value {
          number_value: 0.007015091678270283
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Housing"
        value {
          number_value: 0.055101036115872845
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Job"
        value {
          number_value: 0.021222775094579954
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Loan"
        value {
          number_value: 0.002048753814978598
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "MaritalStatus"
        value {
          number_value: 0.005709941134721149
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Month"
        value {
          number_value: 0.12325089337437695
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "PDays"
        value {
          number_value: 0.023952343173674555
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "POutcome"
        value {
          number_value: 0.06695149606670256
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "Previous"
        value {
          number_value: 0.03921166116430856
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**From "Evaluate" page:**
[image]

**EDIT: 20210920**

I used my regressions model and get the data using aiplatform library. Still I got the attribute `model_explanation`. I'm using `google-cloud-aiplatform==1.4.3` for the library version.

**Code used:**

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

api_endpoint = 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
client_model = aiplatform.gapic.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
#client_model = aiplatform.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)

project_id = 'your-project-id'
location = 'us-central1'
model_id = '999999999'

model_name = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
list_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluations(parent=model_name)
print(list_eval)
```

**Full JSON response:**

```
ListModelEvaluationsPager<model_evaluations {
  name: "projects/xxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/models/99999999/evaluations/8888888"
  metrics_schema_uri: "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/modelevaluation/regression_metrics_1.0.0.yaml"
  metrics {
    struct_value {
      fields {
        key: "meanAbsoluteError"
        value {
          number_value: 0.1303236
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "meanAbsolutePercentageError"
        value {
          number_value: 9.991856
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "rSquared"
        value {
          number_value: 0.39691383
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "rootMeanSquaredError"
        value {
          number_value: 0.24697715
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "rootMeanSquaredLogError"
        value {
          number_value: 0.10037828
        }
      }
    }
  }
  create_time {
    seconds: 1632106497
    nanos: 416614000
  }
  model_explanation {
    mean_attributions {
      feature_attributions {
        struct_value {
          fields {
            key: "Age"
            value {
              number_value: 0.033690840005874634
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Balance"
            value {
              number_value: 0.021756498143076897
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Campaign"
            value {
              number_value: 0.03156016394495964
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Contact"
            value {
              number_value: 0.09849491715431213
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Day"
            value {
              number_value: 0.08989512920379639
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Default"
            value {
              number_value: 0.00012870959471911192
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Duration"
            value {
              number_value: 0.3097792863845825
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Education"
            value {
              number_value: 0.01789841242134571
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Housing"
            value {
              number_value: 0.05525226518511772
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Job"
            value {
              number_value: 0.010000345297157764
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Loan"
            value {
              number_value: 0.00856288243085146
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "MaritalStatus"
            value {
              number_value: 0.01715957187116146
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Month"
            value {
              number_value: 0.22002224624156952
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "PDays"
            value {
              number_value: 0.026749607175588608
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "POutcome"
            value {
              number_value: 0.05268073454499245
            }
          }
          fields {
            key: "Previous"
            value {
              number_value: 0.00636840146034956
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
>
```

**From "Evaluate" page:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but it does not work for me. When I run your code with the my porject_id, location and model_id it returns the error: **AttributeError: 'model_explanation'**,  But when I navigate to the "Evaluation" page I can see the feature importance bar chart just like what you have posted.
My ListModelEvaluationsPager object looks like this:
```{
  name: "..."
  metrics_schema_uri: "..."
  metrics {
    struct_value {
      fields {
        key: "meanAbsoluteError"
        value {
          number_value: 27.391115
        }
      }...```

Comment: The ListModelEvaluationsPager object does not have ```model_explanation```!

Comment: I can't post pictures in the comment otherwise I would include the Eavalutaion page picture for you also the comment is too restrictive and does not allow me to include the entire ListModelEvaluationsPager objcet for you to see.

Comment: please see my post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226029/access-feature-importance-from-trained-vertex-ai-tabular-regression-model-using) with the picture and code returns.

Comment: @Zotara I used [aiplatform_v1](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/services.html) for the solution as this version has the proper documentation. I'll check this using aiplatform.

Comment: @Zotara Apologies it seems I missed the part where you are using regression model. In my example I used classification. I'll also check on this.

Comment: @Zotara I double checked with testing using aiplatform and a regression model, I still get `model_explanation`. See edited answer. What `google-cloud-aiplatform` version are you using?

Comment: Hi Ricco D thanks for clearing this up I sued an earlier version when I installed the 1.4.3 it worked like a charm!!!!!