# Access feature importance from trained Vertex AI Tabular regression model using Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-ai-platform

I am working with models trained using the Tabular automl of Vertex in GCP.
Training and batch predictions work fine. I am trying to use the feature importance in visualizations and trying to get to them from within python.
I can get to the model evaluations with the code @Ricco D posted for me:

```
api_endpoint = 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint} # api_endpoint is required for client_options
client_model = aiplatform.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
project_id = 't...1'
location = 'us-central1'
model_id = '6...2'

model_name = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
list_eval_request = aiplatform.types.ListModelEvaluationsRequest(parent=model_name)
list_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluations(request=list_eval_request)
for val in list_eval:
    print(val.model_explanation)
```

But I can not figure out how to get the trained model's feature importance's that were generated in the training pipeline. I can see them on the model page but can't access them from python:
[image: Evaluation page]

The code returned **ListModelEvaluationsPager** object is this:

````
  name: "projects/7...3/locations/us-central1/models/6...2/evaluations/5...0"
  metrics_schema_uri: "gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/modelevaluation/regression_metrics_1.0.0.yaml"
  metrics {
    struct_value {
      fields {
        key: "meanAbsoluteError"
        value {
          number_value: 27.391115
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "meanAbsolutePercentageError"
        value {
          number_value: 25.082605
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "rSquared"
        value {
          number_value: 0.88434035
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "rootMeanSquaredError"
        value {
          number_value: 47.997845
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "rootMeanSquaredLogError"
        value {
          number_value: nan
        }
      }
    }
  }
  create_time {
    seconds: 1630550819
    nanos: 842478000
  }
}
>```

This object does not have a model_explanation member and the code returns an error
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution with code was posted to answer this by Ricco D here [Correct answer by Ricco D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214803/get-feature-importance-from-trained-vertex-ai-tabular-regression-model-using-pyt)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Feature attributions are included in Vertex AI predictions through [Vertex Explainable AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/explainable-ai/overview).

For batch predictions, you need to set [generate_explanation](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/types.html?highlight=generate_explanation#google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.BatchPredictionJob.generate_explanation) to `True` in your python [BatchPredictionJob](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform_v1/types.html?highlight=generate_explanation#google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.BatchPredictionJob) class like in this example from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/batch-predictions#:%7E:text=Requesting%20a%20batch%20prediction%20using%20BigQuery):
*Note that Feature importance is not supported when the prediction data is returned in Cloud Storage or for forecasting models.*

```py
batch_prediction_job = {
        "display_name": display_name,
        # Format: 'projects/{project}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
        "model": model_name,
        "model_parameters": model_parameters,
        "input_config": {
            "instances_format": instances_format,
            "bigquery_source": {"input_uri": bigquery_source_input_uri},
        },
        "output_config": {
            "predictions_format": predictions_format,
            "bigquery_destination": {"output_uri": bigquery_destination_output_uri},
        },
        # optional
        "generate_explanation": True,
```